# youtube-dl doesn't work as expected in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, youtube-dl

I've made this code to download just the audio from a url on youtube but some links doesn't work

```
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yijULf4Hko" #  doesn't work for example
#video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKK3Y6iDk_Q" #  does work

filename = "song.mp3"

options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'keepvideo': False,
    'outtmpl': filename,
    'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '251',
        }],
    }

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url])
```

when i try with the first link the program outputs this:

```
[youtube] 5yijULf4Hko: Downloading webpage
ERROR: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 2364, in _real_extract
    self._sort_formats(formats)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 1327, in _sort_formats
    raise ExtractorError('No video formats found')
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Scripts/Python/a.py", line 20, in <module>
    ydl.download([video_url])
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2018, in download
    res = self.extract_info(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i'm using the latest version of pycharm (2020.2.1)
already tried to update youtube-dl
i tried to download on command prompt and it dowloaded the audio file successfully
`youtube-dl -f 251 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yijULf4Hko`

At first a thought it was some problem with copyright but it also didn't work with some urls that i was sure wasn't copyrighted

Comment: Looks like the content is different for the broken vid and the library cannot handle it. I suggest you raise an issue like the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that solved it, but it feels like i'm doing it very wrong,
i changed the line:

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url])
```

to

```
import os


try:
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        ydl.download([video_url])
except:
    os.system(f"""youtube-dl -o "song.%(ext)s" --extract-audio -x --audio-format mp3 {video_url}""")
```

i just used the command that worked on the command prompt on the program, but i could not get the python library to work like this, if anyone knows how to properly fix this i will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script i editted, it works for me but you guys can try

```
    @bp.route("/down", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def download_file():
    video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
    url=video_url, download=False
     )
    filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"
    ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'keepvideo': False,
            'outtmpl': filename,
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
        video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)

    path = f'C:\\{video_title}.mp3'

    ydl_opts.update({'outtmpl':path})

    try:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
            ydl.download([video_url])
    except:
        os.system(f"""youtube-dl -o "{filename}.%(ext)s" --extract-audio -x --audio-format mp3 {video_url}""")

        return index()
```

html code

```
    <form action="/down" method="post">
    <button>
    <a type="submit"><i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt" style="color: white;"> MP3</i></a>
    </button> 
    </form>
```